# SharePoint Online API for trending documents in mysite

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api, office365apis

Is there any API to fetch all the trending documents in My Site.

Answer (score 0):

We can get trending documents from a particular location(like shared documents).
Please refer below code,

```
var queryTrendingUrl = "/_api/search/query?querytext='path:http://siteurl/ShearedDocuments/'&sortlist='ViewsLifeTime:descending'";
getItems(queryTrendingUrl).done(function (data) {
    data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results.forEach(function (item) {
        //Get doc properties like below
        var docTitle = item.Cells.results[3]["Value"];
    });
}); 


//Get Data from sharepoint list or library
function getItems(url) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
}
```